# Adding custom Components from a Project to a Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Components from another Project, added to the Solution, not appearing or grey in the toolbox.

Comment: Look into Toolbox -> Choose Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the components not appearing normally under the project name in the toolbox and are greyed out is because the sub-project is not compiled in the same target framework as the solution.

In my example, solution's target framework was 2.0, while the sub-project's was 3.5. As soon as I recompiled the sub-project with 2.0, the components inside were available in the toolbox.